# Transfert file(s) from Windows computer to a phone via USB with a Java application

Tags: java, android, usb, adb

I have to transfert some files from my computer to a phone **programmatically**, but I don't know how to do that.

I've search on the web, and I saw that I could use **ADB** to push files to an Android phone, but on my computer, *no devices are founds* (with command `adb devices`).

So I search an other way to transfert files via USB. Maybe there is something like USB key (send files with the USB letter).

I tried to create a .link file that point to the device, and I read it. Here is a line of it :
`Provider\Microsoft.Base.DeviceDisplayObjects//DDO:{2E2538BA-D737-5194-8FA4-771241BD6E8E}`

Is there any way to transfert a file programmatically with Java (or mayby another language) with that line (I think registery key)?

What is **DDO** ?

Comment: Do you want to _push_ the files to a specific device or shall the user be able to initiate a download on the device? And does it have to be via USB?

Comment: Here is the process: the user plug in the device in USB port, go to the application and the files are generated and transfered automatically via USB. I've already done a transfert via FTP, but I've no wifi in the user's location

Comment: When you plug your device to the pc, does the os mount a filesystem? Like in windows, will there be a new drive detected? If not, have you tried at a different machine?